# Ore theorem vs Dirac theorem- when to use what?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Yesterday I asked a question about how to find hamiltonian paths and circuits in a graph, and I got the following answer:

> > According to the theorem of Ore (to find paths):
>
> Let $G$ be a (finite and simple) graph with $n \geq 3$ vertices. We
>   denote by $\deg v$ the degree of a vertex $v$ in $G$, i.e. the number
>   of incident edges in $G$ to $v$. Then, Ore's theorem states that if
>
> $\deg v + \deg w \geq n$ for every pair of non-adjacent vertices $v$ and
>   $w$ of $G$
>
> then $G$ is Hamiltonian.
>
> According to the theorem of Dirac (to find circuits):
>
> A simple graph with $n$ vertices $(n \geq 3)$ is Hamiltonian if every
>   vertex has degree $n / 2$ or greater.

So after doing some exercises in the book, I got a bit confused. On one question they are using Ore's theorem to prove that there is a circuit. How?

Also in the book, they have given the following formulas:

> $\deg x + \deg y \geq n$  then we have a hamilton circuit.
>
> $\deg x + \deg y \geq n-1$  then we have a hamilton circuit.

So I am confused about which formula to use?  When should I use Ore's theorem and when should I use Dirac's theorem?

Comment: From what you've said, Ore's theorem is strictly more widely applicable. Whenever you use Dirac's theorem, you could instead use Ore's theorem, because if every vertex has degree $\frac{n}{2}$ or more, it is certainly true that the sum of the degrees of any two nonadjacent vertices is greater than or equal to $n$.

Comment: alright, so i guess its ok to use Dirac to find circuits while ores to find paths. How about the diffrence in formulas (diffrence between the formulas the guy gave me and the formula i got from the book) ? are they equivalent  ?

Comment: Ore's theorem will not give you paths, according to what you've written above. It only guarantees cycles. Of course, any cycle reduces to a path, but Ore's theorem may miss the presence of a Hamiltonian path (consider the 3-vertex path graph, for instance, which has a Hamiltonian path, fails Ore's, and has no Hamiltonian cycle.) You can turn a cycle-finding procedure into a path-finding procedure by adding another vertex to the graph, connected to everything, but there's no reason to restrict to Dirac for finding cycles.

Comment: $\text{deg}(x) + \text{deg}(y) \geq n-1$ is insufficient for a Hamiltonian circuit. Consider the path graph on three vertices.

Comment: still confused about when to use what . Lets you have got a question, does a graph with 4 vertices have a hamiltonian path or hamiltonian ciruits?. which forumlas would you have used ? . Add it as answer so i mark it as an answer as well. :)